# C++ OpenCV2 cv::Mat::copyTo error in linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

while trying to compile the following code in OpenCV2 in linux,

```
cv::Mat image1, image2;
cv::Rect rect1, rect2;
...
image1(rect1).copyTo(image2(rect2));
```

I get the following error:

> x.cpp: In member function ‘cv::Mat Process(cv::Mat)’:
>   x.cpp:241: error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::Mat)’
>   cxcore.hpp:794: note: candidates are: void cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::Mat&) const
>   cxcore.hpp:796: note:                 void cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&) const

**Note:** this code compiles and runs flawlessly in windows.

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i see [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html), operator() for Mat needs an argument of type Mat and not Mat&. That seems to be the issue here.

Try adding a temporary objet of type Mat. See below.

```
cv::Mat image1, image2;
cv::Rect rect1, rect2;
...
cv::Mat extractedImage2 = image1(rect2);
image1(rect1).copyTo(extractedImage2);
```

But i must say i am no openCV expert, so that is just an answer based on my c++ knowledge.

Comment: thanks, I didn't get the description well but your code compiles quite well :)

Comment: Should "cv::Mat extractedImage2 = image1(rect2);" be changed to "cv::Mat extractedImage2 = image2(rect2);" ?